# Make Ionic App visible only for mobile phone

Tags: ionic-framework, oauth, oauth-2.0, ionic2

My app does not have registration. my App get it's data from API. I want to my client could not try my API url.

Is OAuth2 applicable here? If yes, please explain.

How can I make My API visible only for trusted mobile phones?

And how can I prevent the use of my API publicly ?

Answer (score 1):

CORS is only an issue when running your app in development mode with ionic serve, and not when running as a mobile app packaged with Cordova
You should also go through this link http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: I have API that fetch my app's data, I want to secure that from being public by monitor HTTP request